# JavaScript client for Restful webservice with SSL

Tags: javascript, rest, ssl

I want to connect to a Java Restful webservice that uses SSL from a Javascript client.
           I could write standalone Java client that connects to the keystore and imports the certificates and could connect successfully.
           How can I achieve the same thing using Javascript, XMLHttpRequest.
   Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: is the question how to setup the server, or how to connect?  You should have to do nothing with the xhrs but use https as the protocol.

Comment: question is one how to connect to a Reastfulw webservice with SSL

Comment: question is one how to connect to a Reastfulw webservice with SSL  using a javascript client

Comment: just make sure your url is using 'https...'  if the server is configured properly it will work

Comment: Are you trying to use a different set of trusted CA certificates than the ones that are in your browser already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  But, to make a SSL asynchronous request against a server with JavaScript, the only change you need to make is to use https in your RESTful target URL instead of http.